# Writing a class file from scratch and getting "Missing \begin{document}" error

Tags: macros, compiling, document-classes, documentclass-writing

I'm looking to write my own class file for a couple of reasons, but my main interest is better understanding LaTeX and how it works. I understand that I likely don't *need* to define my own class for whatever I want to do, but I'm interested in learning the A to Z on what a LaTeX document needs in order to compile correctly (and with minimal fragility).

The resources I've found so far for creating a class seem to be leaving out key information. [Overleaf's guide](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Writing_your_own_class) seems to indicate that you only need the `\NeedsTeXFormat` and `\ProvidesClass` commands in order to have a working class. Through trial and error, I've also found that `\normalsize` also needs to be defined.

Other resources and examples I've found use the `\LoadClass` command, which I'm sure copies over common settings and commands that make adding onto the class easier, but I'm not finding resources that otherwise *don't* do this.

Here's the code I have so far:

```latex
%%% myclass.cls %%%

% Required per Overleaf
% https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Writing_your_own_class
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2023/01/31 Version 0.1 by Me]

% Required Font Sizes
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{10pt}
```

```latex
%%% example.tex %%%
\documentclass{myclass}

\begin{document}
   Hello World!
\end{document}
```

This produces the error:

> example.tex:4: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

My understanding is that something is missing from the class file that doesn't allow the compiler to see the contents of `example.tex`, but I'm not sure what it is. Searching for this error comes up with *a lot* of results to work around of poorly-written packages or fix beginner errors, but little to no results on how to write *good* packages (or classes).

Any help or resources is appreciated!

Comment: the default definition of `\normalsize` is something like `\renewcommand\normalsize{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont}`, so it shouldn't print something but select a font. See the minimal.cls and article.cls for small classes.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Thanks, this fixed it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the definition of `\normalsize` you have:

```bash
$ latexdef normalsize                                            

\normalsize:
macro:->\protect \normalsize  


\normalsize :
\long macro:->\@setfontsize \normalsize \@xpt \@xiipt \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 5\p@
 \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus 3\p@ \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus 3\p@ \@minus 3\p@ \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip \let 
\@listi \@listI
```

You are changing it to the *text* "10 pt" which, when called before the `\begin{document}` by the format, creates an unexpected text that give the error.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. The fixed implementation is using `\renewcommand\normalsize{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont}` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Though the Overleaf Guide you cite seems to be quite good, I still prefer rereading *"The LaTeX Companion"* for this purpose.

First, it provides a nice structure, which I incorporate as comments in whatever class I might be trying, and which is a bit unclear to my taste from said guide:

```
% ~~~ identification ~~~~~~~~~

% ~~~ initial code ~~~~~~~

% ~~~ declaration of options ~~~~~~~~~

% ~~~ execution of options ~~~~~~

% ~~~ package loading ~~~~~~~~~~

% === main code ==========
```

Second, it's important to understand/recall the logic behind. Sticking to this order minimizes trouble to my experience.

Third, it clarifies special commands to be used with package and/or class files.